# HTML buttons that copy their own .innerHTML text content to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, button, copy

Does anyone know how to make buttons that copy their own text to the clipboard with JavaScript?

**My Code:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementByClassName("copy");
  
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<button class="copy">Click to copy this text data to clipboard.</button>
<button class="copy">Click to copy this different text data to clipboard.</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` is defined on text in an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element only. You could create the node element dynamically and set its `innerText` with the value of the button:

```js
const copyToClipboard = text => {
  const ta = document.createElement("textarea");
  ta.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(ta);
  ta.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(ta);
};

for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll(".copy")) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", e => {
    copyToClipboard(e.target.innerText);
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="copy">Click to copy this text data to clipboard.</button>
<button class="copy">Click to copy this different text data to clipboard.</button>
```

A more elegant option exists and is Chrome/FF compatible: [`Clipboard.writeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText).

You'll need `"clipboard-write"` permission on the frame to perform the copy, which might not work in the stack snippet below.

```js
for (const elem of document.getElementsByClassName("copy")) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", e => 
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.innerText)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  );
}
```

```html
<button class="copy">Click to copy this text data to clipboard.</button>
<button class="copy">Click to copy this different text data to clipboard.</button>
```

Comment: I used the Clipboard.writeText method, which works really great! Only tested on FF btw. Maybe an alert / message that the content is copied would make this solution even more useful :-) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("btn");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.textContent)
}
```

Comment: This would be the easies / best solution if there was only one button, but when there's more than 1 button this solution doesn't work unfortunately :-(