# In the plinko game written with the matter.js engine library, how to make the ball always fall into the pre-planned position

Tags: javascript, collision, matter.js

Please take the following code as an example. How can I make the ball always fall seemingly randomly every time into the third space position in the bottom?

What I can think of is to constantly judge its collision position during the falling process of the ball, and let the ball move towards the target, but how to make the moving process appear natural and random stumps me.
you can view it in:https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sunset-t7s794?file=/index.html

[The effect I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI4Hx.png)

```js
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Body = Matter.Body;

// create an engine
const engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
const render = Render.create({
  element: document.getElementById('can'),
  engine: engine
});
// create flanges
const fOptions = {
  isStatic: true,
}
const flanges = [
  //row one
  Bodies.polygon(45, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(100, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(60, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(100, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row two
  Bodies.polygon(150, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(200, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(150, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(200, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row three
  Bodies.polygon(250, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(300, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(250, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(300, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row four
  Bodies.polygon(350, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(400, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(350, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(400, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row five
  Bodies.polygon(450, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(500, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(450, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(500, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row six
  Bodies.polygon(550, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(600, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(550, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(600, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row seven
  Bodies.polygon(650, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(700, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(650, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(700, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  //row 8
  Bodies.polygon(755, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(740, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
];
for (i = 0; i < flanges.length; i++) {
  World.add(engine.world, [flanges[i]])
  Body.setAngle(flanges[i], 16.23)
}
//create catches
const cOptions = {
  isStatic: true
}
const catches = [
  Bodies.rectangle(40, 560, 2, 40, cOptions)
];
xasx = 82;
for (v = 0; v < 20; v++) {
  catches.push(Bodies.rectangle(xasx, 560, 2, 40, cOptions))
  World.add(engine.world, [catches[v]])
  xasx = xasx + 45;
}
// create disk
let disk = [];
let count = 0;
const dOptions = {
  friction: .2,
  restitution: 1
}

function addD() {
  disk.push(Bodies.circle(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 20, dOptions))
  World.add(engine.world, [disk[count]])
  count++
}
// create ground sky and walls
const ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, {
  isStatic: true
});
const leftWall = Bodies.rectangle(0, 305, 2, 810, {
  isStatic: true
});
const righttWall = Bodies.rectangle(800, 305, 2, 810, {
  isStatic: true
});
const sky = Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 810, 2, {
  isStatic: true
});
// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [sky, righttWall, leftWall, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

body {
  background-color: #353535;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', serif;
  color: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(pink, blueviolet);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

hr {
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  border-radius: 90%;
  background-color: pink;
  color: pink;
}

h4 {
  margin-top: 3%;
  color: darkorange;
}

a {
  color: darkorange;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Plinko</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy" />
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>PlinkO</h1>
    <hr />
    <aside onclick="addD()" id="can"></aside>
  </center>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What sort of result are you looking to achieve? If this is a one-off animation, you could run MJS capturing the ball position at each frame until you get the desired result. Then remove MJS completely and create a simple canvas animation that puts the ball (and any other objects) in the exact positions you got from the MJS run earlier--totally deterministic, but limited only to whatever you've pre-recorded. BTW, `World` is deprecated.

Comment: I haven't looked into determinism in MJS before, but apparently you can set a seed according to [Outcome always different in matter.js physics engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210236/outcome-always-different-in-matter-js-physics-engine). My first suggestion is in [MatterJS precompute final position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847252/matterjs-precompute-final-position). Do either of these answer your question? Another aside: you've created a bunch of globals here which are susceptible to bugs--always use `const` or `let` on variable declarations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This game will be used repeatedly, and the desired result is that the landing point of each falling ball can be controlled in advance. For example, the control of the ball falling into the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th spaces at the bottom Here, can you show your ideas with code, I don't understand some

Comment: If you are using MatterJS browser and need deterministic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77872867/4421162

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75642529/in-the-plinko-game-written-with-the-matter-js-engine-library-how-to-make-the-ba#comment133452559_75642529), one approach is to run the simulation ahead of time, capturing the positions of the bodies that correspond to the desired behavior. Once you have an array of position data, you can run the animation for the user, setting live body positions by reading from the position data step by step.

Here's a proof of concept that guarantees the first "disk" will fall deterministically into the third pocket (click the game area to create a disk):

```js
const {Bodies, Body, Composite, Engine, Events, Render, Runner} = Matter;
const engine = Engine.create();
const render = Render.create({
  element: document.getElementById("can"),
  engine: engine,
});
const fOptions = {isStatic: true};
const flanges = [
  // row one
  Bodies.polygon(45, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(100, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(60, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(100, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row two
  Bodies.polygon(150, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(200, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(150, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(200, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row three
  Bodies.polygon(250, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(300, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(250, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(300, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row four
  Bodies.polygon(350, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(400, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(350, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(400, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row five
  Bodies.polygon(450, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(500, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(450, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(500, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row six
  Bodies.polygon(550, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(600, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(550, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(600, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row seven
  Bodies.polygon(650, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(700, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(650, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(700, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row 8
  Bodies.polygon(755, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(740, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
];

for (let i = 0; i < flanges.length; i++) {
  Composite.add(engine.world, [flanges[i]]);
  Body.setAngle(flanges[i], 16.23);
}

const cOptions = {isStatic: true};
const catches = [Bodies.rectangle(40, 560, 2, 40, cOptions)];
let xasx = 82;

for (let v = 0; v < 20; v++) {
  catches.push(Bodies.rectangle(xasx, 560, 2, 40, cOptions));
  Composite.add(engine.world, [catches[v]]);
  xasx = xasx + 45;
}

const disk = [];
const dOptions = {friction: 0.2, restitution: 1};

function addD() {
  disk.push(
    Bodies.circle(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 20, dOptions)
  );
  Composite.add(engine.world, [disk.at(-1)]);
}

const ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, {isStatic: true});
const leftWall = Bodies.rectangle(0, 305, 2, 810, {isStatic: true});
const righttWall = Bodies.rectangle(800, 305, 2, 810, {isStatic: true});
const sky = Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 810, 2, {isStatic: true});
Composite.add(engine.world, [
  sky,
  righttWall,
  leftWall,
  ground,
]);

const positions = getPositions();
let currPosition = 0;
Events.on(engine, "beforeUpdate", () => {
  if (disk[0] && currPosition < positions.length) {
    const pos = {
      x: positions[currPosition][0],
      y: positions[currPosition++][1],
    };
    Body.setPosition(disk[0], pos);
  }
});
Runner.run(engine);
Render.run(render);

function getPositions() {return [[66,63],[66,63.27],[66,63.83],[66,64.65],[66,65.75],[66,67.11],[66,68.73],[66,70.62],[66,72.77],[66,75.17],[66,77.82],[66,80.73],[66,83.89],[66,87.29],[66,90.93],[66,94.82],[66,98.95],[66,103.31],[66,107.91],[66,112.74],[66,117.79],[66,123.08],[66.88,128.08],[71.14,130.44],[75.36,133.06],[79.54,135.93],[83.67,139.05],[87.76,142.41],[91.82,146.02],[95.83,149.87],[99.80,153.96],[103.74,158.29],[107.63,162.85],[111.48,167.65],[115.30,172.67],[119.08,177.92],[122.82,183.40],[126.52,189.10],[130.18,195.02],[133.81,201.16],[137.41,207.51],[140.96,214.08],[144.48,220.86],[147.97,227.85],[151.42,235.05],[154.84,242.46],[158.22,250.07],[161.57,257.88],[163.76,266.09],[166.91,273.53],[170.02,281.17],[173.10,289.01],[176.15,297.05],[179.16,305.29],[182.15,313.72],[185.11,322.35],[188.04,331.17],[190.94,340.17],[193.81,349.37],[196.65,358.75],[199.47,368.32],[202.25,378.07],[205.01,387.99],[207.74,398.10],[210.44,408.38],[214.95,417.20],[224.36,420.72],[233.67,424.48],[242.89,428.48],[252.01,432.72],[261.05,437.20],[270.00,441.90],[270.22,441.88],[261.58,437.65],[253.02,433.74],[244.55,430.15],[236.16,426.87],[227.86,423.90],[219.64,421.24],[213.76,417.20],[214.19,409.81],[214.62,402.77],[215.04,396.07],[215.46,389.72],[215.87,383.72],[216.28,378.05],[216.69,372.71],[215.59,368.58],[211.37,367.48],[207.20,366.68],[203.07,366.16],[198.99,365.93],[194.94,365.97],[190.93,366.29],[186.97,366.89],[184.47,368.49],[186.39,371.71],[188.30,375.17],[190.19,378.88],[192.06,382.83],[193.92,387.02],[195.75,391.45],[197.57,396.11],[199.36,400.99],[201.14,406.11],[202.93,410.66],[204.46,405.76],[205.98,401.19],[207.48,396.95],[208.97,393.02],[210.44,389.41],[211.90,386.12],[213.34,383.13],[214.77,380.46],[216.19,378.08],[217.59,376.01],[218.97,374.25],[217.20,375.82],[215.45,377.65],[213.72,379.74],[212.01,382.09],[210.32,384.70],[208.64,387.55],[206.97,390.65],[205.33,394.00],[203.70,397.60],[202.09,401.44],[200.49,405.51],[198.91,409.82],[196.34,410.57],[193.56,407.66],[190.81,405.06],[188.09,402.76],[185.39,400.77],[182.73,399.07],[180.09,397.66],[177.47,396.55],[174.88,395.72],[172.32,395.19],[169.78,394.93],[167.27,394.96],[164.78,395.26],[162.32,395.84],[159.89,396.69],[157.47,397.81],[155.08,399.19],[152.72,400.84],[150.38,402.75],[148.06,404.92],[145.77,407.35],[143.50,410.03],[141.25,412.96],[139.02,416.14],[136.82,419.56],[134.63,423.23],[132.47,427.14],[130.34,431.29],[128.22,435.67],[128.14,439.12],[132.68,439.23],[137.18,439.62],[141.63,440.29],[146.03,441.22],[150.39,442.43],[154.71,443.90],[158.98,445.63],[163.21,447.63],[165.99,449.07],[162.16,446.61],[158.37,444.46],[154.62,442.60],[150.91,441.04],[147.23,439.78],[143.59,438.80],[139.99,438.11],[136.42,437.71],[132.88,437.59],[129.39,437.74],[127.30,437.38],[129.56,435.69],[131.79,434.29],[134.01,433.19],[136.20,432.37],[138.37,431.84],[140.52,431.60],[142.65,431.63],[144.75,431.94],[146.83,432.52],[148.90,433.38],[150.94,434.51],[152.96,435.90],[154.97,437.56],[156.95,439.48],[158.91,441.65],[160.85,444.08],[162.78,446.77],[164.68,449.71],[164.46,452.25],[161.41,453.35],[158.39,454.72],[155.40,456.36],[152.43,458.25],[149.50,460.41],[146.60,462.82],[143.72,465.48],[140.88,468.40],[138.06,471.56],[135.27,474.97],[132.51,478.63],[129.78,482.52],[127.07,486.66],[124.39,491.03],[121.74,495.63],[119.12,500.47],[116.52,505.54],[113.94,510.83],[111.40,516.35],[108.87,522.09],[106.38,528.05],[103.91,534.23],[102.94,540.62],[105.24,546.46],[106.05,552.51],[103.90,558.00],[102.88,560.18],[102.88,555.63],[102.77,552.19],[102.76,549.84],[102.96,548.62],[103.17,547.68],[103.37,547.04],[103.56,546.67],[103.76,546.59],[103.95,546.79],[104.15,547.26],[104.34,548.01],[104.53,549.02],[104.71,550.31],[104.90,551.86],[105.08,553.67],[105.26,555.74],[105.44,558.07],[105.62,560.21],[105.37,557.87],[105.12,555.84],[104.88,554.11],[104.63,552.67],[104.39,551.53],[104.16,550.67],[103.92,550.10],[103.69,549.82],[103.46,549.81],[103.23,550.08],[103.01,550.63],[102.87,551.45],[102.86,551.88],[102.87,552.28],[102.88,552.62],[102.88,552.93],[102.89,553.30],[102.90,553.72],[102.90,554.21],[102.90,554.78],[102.90,555.49],[102.89,556.32],[102.84,557.23],[102.81,558.19],[102.78,559.41],[102.83,560.17],[103.29,560.12],[103.69,560.17],[104.08,560.09],[104.45,560.12],[104.80,560.21],[105.14,560.05],[105.34,560.05],[105.53,560.06],[105.72,560.19],[105.99,560.08],[106.10,560.10],[106.01,560.22],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11],[106.11,560.11]];};
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<aside onclick="addD()" id="can"></aside>
```

Most of the relevant code is at the bottom, near the `beforeUpdate` event handler.

Here's the "instrumented" code I used to create the positions array (again, most of the relevant code is at the bottom):

```js
const {Bodies, Body, Composite, Engine, Events, Render, Runner} = Matter;
const engine = Engine.create();
const render = Render.create({
  element: document.getElementById("can"),
  engine: engine,
});
const fOptions = {isStatic: true};
const flanges = [
  // row one
  Bodies.polygon(45, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(100, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(60, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(100, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row two
  Bodies.polygon(150, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(200, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(150, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(200, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row three
  Bodies.polygon(250, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(300, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(250, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(300, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row four
  Bodies.polygon(350, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(400, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(350, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(400, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row five
  Bodies.polygon(450, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(500, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(450, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(500, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row six
  Bodies.polygon(550, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(600, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(550, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(600, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row seven
  Bodies.polygon(650, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(700, 250, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(650, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(700, 450, 3, 20, fOptions),
  // row 8
  Bodies.polygon(755, 150, 3, 20, fOptions),
  Bodies.polygon(740, 350, 3, 20, fOptions),
];

for (let i = 0; i < flanges.length; i++) {
  Composite.add(engine.world, [flanges[i]]);
  Body.setAngle(flanges[i], 16.23);
}

const cOptions = {isStatic: true};
const catches = [Bodies.rectangle(40, 560, 2, 40, cOptions)];
let xasx = 82;

for (let v = 0; v < 20; v++) {
  catches.push(Bodies.rectangle(xasx, 560, 2, 40, cOptions));
  Composite.add(engine.world, [catches[v]]);
  xasx = xasx + 45;
}

const disk = [];
const dOptions = {friction: 0.2, restitution: 1};

function addD() {
  disk.push(
    Bodies.circle(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 20, dOptions)
  );
  Composite.add(engine.world, [disk.at(-1)]);
}

const ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, {isStatic: true});
const leftWall = Bodies.rectangle(0, 305, 2, 810, {isStatic: true});
const righttWall = Bodies.rectangle(800, 305, 2, 810, {isStatic: true});
const sky = Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 810, 2, {isStatic: true});
Composite.add(engine.world, [
  sky,
  righttWall,
  leftWall,
  ground,
]);
const positions = [];
let currPosition = 0;
Events.on(engine, "beforeUpdate", () => {
  if (disk[0]) {
    positions.push(Object.values(disk[0].position));
  }
});
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(positions.map(e => e.map(e => +e.toFixed(2)))));
});
Runner.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<button>log positions</button>
<aside onclick="addD()" id="can"></aside>
```

I ran the instrumented snippet above repeatedly until I reached the desired run, then clicked the button to log the positions. Next, I copied the data from the browser console to my clipboard (this can be done [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883472/6243352)) and into the top snippet.

I used an array for each position to save a bit of storage space, which requires converting it into an x/y vector object before calling `setPosition`. I also trimmed some of the precision from the position decimals to save more space. These are probably premature optimizations, but are good to keep in mind for many use cases. Other space optimizations are possible, like dropping every other frame and using interpolation to recreate the animation.

A more elegant and scalable alternative to the quick and dirty method described above is to run Matter.js in Node and write the positions to file. If the desired state is hard to reproduce, you can programmatically run your Matter.js code repeatedly and capture the position array to file conditionally. This is also useful for generating a series of similar runs that you can randomly pick from. For the use case here, a group of dozens of runs that all reach the third pocket is probably enough to appear realistic.

For some use cases, it may be possible to simulate a number of runs in real-time behind the scenes (for example, when a user first visits a webpage), then pick the "right" one and re-run it for the user. This is useful if you can't transmit a position data structure from a server or need to guarantee run uniqueness. The downsides are coding complexity and real-time demands.

Another consideration for realism is that, in my example code, if the user doesn't click anywhere near where the ball is spawned, it may seem artificial. Fixing this is use-case specific and out of scope for the proof of concept, but one solution is to select the closest from many available paths to the user's click. Another option is to use natural MJS physics until the real disk comes close to a part of the precomputed path, at which point the precomputed path takes over from the natural physics. Lerping the body from the user's click to a precomputed path may also help solve the realism issue.

---

Going a step further, if you're using Matter.js [headlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74911196/6243352) for rendering totally deterministic animations, the techniques described here can be used to avoid sending the MJS library or your MJS code to the client entirely--just use it to precompute hardcoded position data structures behind the scenes and draw them with a generic animation loop!

---

Similar threads:

- [MatterJS precompute final position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847252/matterjs-precompute-final-position) (canonical)
- [Outcome always different in matter.js physics engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210236/outcome-always-different-in-matter-js-physics-engine)
- [GH issue #820](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/820)
- [GH issue #1190](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1190)
- [GH issue #1199](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1199)

---

As a general remark, always use `let` or `const` before your variable declarations. It's easy to forget to do this in `for` loops, but failing to do so introduces a global that can easily clash with a window variable or alias its way to a bug.

I also changed the code to remove needless comments and avoid using deprecated MJS classes, like World.